# When buying used macbook pro 2010 do I need the cd?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

It seems to me that I shouldn't need the boot cds when buying a used macbook pro if it is upgraded to Yosemite, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, as long as it's running Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion" or later, that MacBook Pro won't require or even be able to make any use of the boot CDs. The reason being that Lion added the built-in Recovery partition, and many features in Recovery were previously only available on the boot disks.

Comment: And in fact Apple no longer ships any kind of bootable media with its Macs. Not sure when this started but it is quite possible this Mac never came with bootable (or any other) media (optical or flash drive).